# Style only show's correct button after refreshing the page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, elementor

we use WordPress and Elementor to build a page. We currently have 2 different checkout systems - one for ourselves and 1 with Shopify for Affiliates.

Because of that, we have 2 "Buy now" buttons, and we display only 1, depending on a cookie "ref".

Our own checkout uses [www.digistore24.com](http://www.digistore24.com) as link and the Affiliate checkout uses neuroprogrammer.myshopify.com..

The ref cookie is set from the Shopify Affiliate plugin, which also is implemented in the WordPress page.

I placed the following code to hide one of the buttons into the header.php:

```html
<?php   if(isset($_COOKIE["ref"])) : ?>
    <style>
      .btn-ds24{
        display: none !important;
      }
    </style>

<?php else: ?>

    <style>
      .btn-shopify{
        display: none !important;
      }
    </style>

<?php endif; ?>
```

My problem now is, that if I open the page with the ref code, the correct button is only visible after refreshing the page again. The cookie is placed correctly after the first load, that's why I can't explain, why it shows the wrong button at first.

You can test it yourself here:
https://biotonics.de/playlist/biotonics-vol-1/?ref=ticverdun

Embedded in the green "Jetzt bestellen" button should be the .myshopify Link, but it's the Digistore24 link.

Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test for `$_COOKIE` & `$_GET`

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["ref"]) || isset($_GET['ref'])) : ?>
    <style>
      .btn-ds24{
        display: none !important;
      }
    </style>

<?php else: ?>

    <style>
      .btn-shopify{
        display: none !important;
      }
    </style>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Awesome, now the right button is visible from the start, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing your code first hand and the order of operations, the only thing I can pick up on is that your cookie, while being set AFTER a person visits a page, may not be set BEFORE this style is generated.

Honestly, this is a bit of a redundant way to do it. You're better off adapting the template itself to the button, rather than using a conditional style to show/hide the button. Makes for a better experience and less prone to errors.

I get that you're using Elementor, and I'm assuming that means you're building these on the fly and somewhat need to use styles, but it's not something I'd generally suggest.

A better option may be to look at a JS library like [js-cookie](https://openbase.com/js/js-cookie) for easy reads, and that way you cun run the test once the browser has actually built (make sure you start with 1 button always hidden, or actively build the URL to the button based on the cookie).
Still a shoddy way to do it, but a more robust, better shoddy way

Comment: I understand you're new and you can't leave a comment but this answer is not an answer.

Comment: So you're saying, with the minimal information that has been given, and no understanding of when the Cookie is set, I should provide a robust answer that outlines what could work?
The best answer that can be given is that his Cookie is not actually set when this check is called the first time around.
If there is a better way to answer this question, or ask a follow-up, I'd be more than happy to have some guidance :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I did place the code once at the footer right at the bottom, to make sure the cookie is already set. But sadly it still loaded the wrong button first and after refreshing the correct button. 

Even if there is no solution to my problem, I would be happy to learn, why it behaves that way.

Comment: If you dump the reference to the cookie, I'll guarantee you'll see it's considered unset. Because of the way WordPress loads themes and core, you're not just contending with everything between the `header.php` and `footer.php`, you also need to consider all core files, system hooks, etc.
I'm guessing that you are setting the cookie in `functions.php` via a hook? I would say this hook fires any active PHP calls after the main theme files that are being built.

You would need to look at the complete WP Lifecycle and force this cookie to be set as early as possible

Comment: This question also lacks proper info. So answering a poor question with an incomplete answer isn't the way to earn reputation. I see you edited your answer after I commented.

Comment: Thanks Howard, I'll keep that in mind